# RestTemplate removes cookie. (Migration from CloseableHttpClient)

Tags: spring, resttemplate, closeablehttpresponse

I need migrate from CloseableHttpClient to RestTemplate in my desctop client application. RestTemplate response has an empty "Set-cookie" header.

Source code (works ok): // returns the Set-Cookie header = "JSESSIONID=D2442..."

```
List<BasicNameValuePair> parameters = asList(
new BasicNameValuePair("username", username),
new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(parameters));

CloseableHttpClient client = createDefault()


CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
```

Target code: // returns the Set-Cookie header = ""

```
        String url = url;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);

        MultiValueMap<String, String> map= new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("username", username);
        map.add("password", password);

        ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, String>> responseType = new ParameterizedTypeReference<>() {};

        HttpEntity<Object> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

        ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>> tokensInfo = restTemplate.exchange(
                url, HttpMethod.POST, request, responseType
        );
```

Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

Add to the target code:

```
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        ClientHttpRequestFactory factory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        restTemplate.setRequestFactory(factory);
```